# output raw text for Javascript CDATA use

Tags: views

I've created a content type with coordinates data for a bunch of projects we're running. I want these coordinates to be output raw into a CDATA block, so that I can mark each project on a Google Map.

Output should look something like this:

> ['Son La',21.335432,103.908691,'1. AFLI
> 2. Gender-specific
>   appreciation of land use and landscape multi-functionality'], ['Dien
>   Bien',21.42239,103.029785,'1. AFLI'],

Unfortunately, my view always includes all kinds of `<div>` elements that obviously break the data format. I can't seem to find where I would set the output to be raw, i.e. without any formatting, and allowing me to use *[ and ]*. Maybe I don't have the right permissions?

Comment: I guess these are the Standard row classes. You can disable these in the row settings.

Comment: Out of "row styles"? I can only select: fields, panel fields, node and semantic fields. CSS class already says none.

Comment: You beer the other link with options. But perhaps it was under display.